# Generating new html Row and Appending to table in JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, row, addition

I've created a table generated from my SQL DB of "patches" in my current "package" for this web page shown here :

```
<table id="PatchTable">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Date
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Detach
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Evironment
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Platform
                    </th>
                    <th>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @{DeploymentMVC.Models.DeploymentDb db = new DeploymentMVC.Models.DeploymentDb();
                  DeploymentMVC.Models.Patch[] patches = db.GetPatches(Model);
                }
                @foreach (var patch in patches)
                {
                    <tr id=@string.Format("patch_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                        <td class="NameDisplay">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(ptch => patch.PatchName)
                        </td>
                        <td class="DateDisplay">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(ptch => patch.PatchDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="pkgID" class="pkgID" value="@Model.PackageID" />
                            <input type="checkbox" class="patchIds" name="patchIdString" value="@patch.PatchID" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id=@string.Format("environment_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                                @patch.Environment
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden" id=@string.Format("SelectEnvironment_{0}", patch.PatchID) >
                                <select name="DeploymentOption" id=@string.Format("EnvironmentValue_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                                    <option value="Staging">Staging</option>
                                    <option value="Live">Live</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @*TODO: Figure out deploy options*@
                            <div id=@string.Format("platform_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                                @patch.Platform
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden" id=@string.Format("SelectPlatform_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                                <select name="Staging Servers" id=@string.Format("PlatformValue_{0}", patch.PatchID)>
                                    <option value="air-cast">air-cast</option>
                                    <option value="redshop">Redshop</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="EditButton">
                                <input type="button" class="button EditButtonInput" value="" id=@string.Format("edit_{0}", patch.PatchID) />
                            </div>
                            <div class="SaveButton">
                                <input type="button" class="button SaveButtonInput hidden" value="" id=@string.Format("save_{0}", patch.PatchID) />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

And then I have another table of non-allocated "patches" that can be added to my table above ^ via a checkbox and submit button. Shown here:

```
<table id="newPatchTable" class="sortable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <div class="pointer">
                                    Name
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <div class="pointer">
                                    Date
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Location
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        @{
                            DeploymentMVC.Models.Patch[] patchArray = DeploymentMVC.Models.DirectoryHelper.GetAllPatches();
                        }
                        @if (patchArray.Length != 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var patch in patchArray)
                            {
                            <tr id=@string.Format("addPatch_{0}", patch.PatchName.Replace(@" ", string.Empty))>
                                <td class="NameDisplay">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patch.PatchName)
                                </td>
                                <td class="DateDisplay">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patch.PatchDate)
                                </td>
                                <td class="LocationDisplay">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => patch.PatchLocation)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="patchNames" class="PatchNames" value="@patch.PatchName" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <a>There are no current patches to add to your package. Please go to the @Html.ActionLink("Deploy Packages", "DeployPackages", "Package")
                                            page to see packages or refresh the page if you recently committed a change are
                                            expecting a patch to show up here. </a><a href="sf-build:8080">Click here to go to TeamCity
                                                to manually build your patch.</a>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </table>
```

I have currently written some javascript to remove the selected "patches" (rows) from my un-allocated patch table (table 2), and added them to the package's patch table (table 1). I know this is not the correct way to do so, but I could not figure out how to use `clone()` and be able to edit the `id`, `class`, and text of each `<tr>`, `<td>`, and `<div>`.

Here is my JS (I've removed some things because I don't think they are necessary for my question):

```
$('#AddSelectedPatches').click(function () {
        ...
            $.each($('.PatchNames:checked'), function (i, element) {
             ...
                                                //Creates row in the package's "Patches" table
                                                var newRow = '<tr id=patch_' + patchID + '>'
                                                                 + '<td class="NameDisplay">' + patchName + '</td>'
                                                                 + '<td class="DateDisplay">' + patchDate + '</td>'
                                                                 + '<td><input type="hidden" name="pkgID" class="pkgID" value=' + $('#pkgID').val() + '/>'
                                                                 + '<input type="checkbox" class="patchIds" name="patchIdString" value=' + patchID + ' /></td>'
                                                                 + '<td><div id=environment_' + patchID + '>' + patchEnvironment + '</div>'
                                                                 + '<div class="hidden" id=SelectEnvironment_' + patchID + '><select name="DeploymentOption" id="EnvironmentValue_" + patch.PatchID>'
                                                                 + '<option value="Staging">Staging</option><option value="Live">Live</option></select></div></td>'
                                                                 + '<td><div id=platform_' + patch.PatchID + '>' + patchPlatform + '</div>'
                                                                 + '<div class="hidden" id=SelectPlatform_' + patchID + '>'
                                                                 + '<select name="Staging Servers" id="PlatformValue_" + patch.PatchID><option value="1">air-cast</option>'
                                                                 + '<option value="2">Redshop</option></select></div></td><td><div class="EditButton"><input type="button" class="button EditButtonInput" value="" id=edit_' + patchID + ' />'
                                                                 + '</div><div class="SaveButton"><input type="button" class="button SaveButtonInput hidden" value="" id=save_' + patchID + ' />'
                                                                 + '</div></td></tr>';
                                                $('#PatchTable').append(newRow);
                                                //Removes row in "New Patches to Add" table
                                                var patchName_noSpaces = patchName.replace(/\s/g, '')

                                                $('#addPatch_' + patchName_noSpaces).remove();
                                            });
        return false;
    });
```

This works for visually adding the patches (and my checkboxes work), but my `EditButtonInput` and hidden `SaveButtonInput` classes do not recognize the javascript created rows (i.e. my `click` events for those two classes do nothing when the JS created ones are clicked). I've checked for spelling mistakes but did not come across any that would cause this problem.

Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: can you paste your javascript where you are attaching event. because if you are using jquery to attach event then you should use method live() to attach event, so jQuery will when adding new element attach events to it eg $('#your_table tr').live('click', function() {});

Comment: @Senad Meškin I have posted my javascript for the attach above. The line "  $('#PatchTable').append(newRow); " is where I add the new row. I am not trying to modify a row on a row click event, but instead on a button click event. Sorry if I did not understand your question clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Men this is no the better way of doing this stuff.

I recommend you tu use 2 connected list using jquery, is so simple!!!(http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists)

And then as Senad pointed you must use .live for elements in the dom that are not created when it loads.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it. I know this is a bad way to do it. I am new to this :)